# Dict with df. How to fill empty data frames which are in values of dictionary?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, append

I created dictionary with data frames. I want to fill each data frame - append new row to each. It is in for loop.
When I have one data frame, and list of values it is works:

```
row = [20, 'Gornik Zabrze', 'Radomiak Radom', 0, 0]
length = len(df)
df.loc[length] = row
```

But when I work with dictionary it doesnt work.

For example I have this code:

```
List = ['Maths','Science','Geography','History','English']
 
Dictionary = {}
 
for i in List:
    Dictionary[i] = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name", "Level", "Country"])
 
print("Created multiple dataframes in a loop:\n", Dictionary)
```

I want to add row for each data frame. But when I use:

```
row = ["Mat", 5, "Poland"]
Dictionary["Maths"].append(row)
```

I get this (new column, it isn`t correct for me):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUt5N.png)

This code also doesnt work and I get Key error:

```
Dictionary["Maths"].loc[0].append(row)
```

I would like to get new row in each data frame in dictionary.

Then I want to add another new row to each, itd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use `concat` to fix your code also `append` has been deprecated in recent pandas versions (>= 1.4.0).

```
cols = ["Name", "Level", "Country"]
Dictionary['Maths'] = pd.concat([Dictionary['Maths'], pd.DataFrame([row], columns=cols)])
```

Result

```
print(Dictionary['Maths'])

  Name Level Country
0  Mat     5  Poland
```

---

Just an FYI: From an optimization POV using concat multiple times in a loop is not a good idea instead you can accumulate all the rows in a loop and then create a DataFrame from those rows.

Comment: Great, thank You @Shubham Sharma. Thanks for advices.